# Need "One-Way" File Sharing Software/SaaS/PaaS

Tags: file-management, file-synchronization, dropbox, data-transfer

At work we have the need for around 100 vendors to send us some files "One-Way".

We need them to drop a file into a drive/box/webapp and then they're done.

We can see all the files/download/etc

But they can either A. Only see their files or B. See nothing at all.

Option A or B will work.

We are trying to avoid using email since vendors will be sending many files over a period of time.

The big requirement is that Vendor A cannot see Vendor B's files and vice-versa.

If we could avoid having to setup and provision accounts/groups/roles/access for the 100 vendors, that would be preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: What size files?  A simple file upload script that emails a confirmation to client and a notice to company worker(s) might work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that DropBox offers a "Request" feature.

https://www.dropbox.com/requests

This solves my issue.